# Get DOM element attribute of parent container with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'am quite new to AngularJS and I try to achieve to following: on click on some outer element and **also on click on it's child elements** I want to get some attribute of the outer element.

In jQuery this seems to bubble up easily when i click the subelement. In Angular, the function I put on "ng-click" on the outer element gets called, but the attribute can't be fetched... 
I put my example with Angular and jQuery here: http://www.allcontrasts.com/external/angular-jquery/index.html

The critial code is the following:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController" >
  <div class="angulardiv" ng-click="myAlert($event);" data-id="321">ANGULAR
    <div class="sublement">
        Subelement
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jquerydiv" data-id="321">JQUERY
    <div class="sublement">
        Subelement
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Angular-Code:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myAlert = function(event) {
        var elem = angular.element(event.target);
        var dataId = elem.attr('data-id');
        alert(dataId);
    }
});
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jquerydiv').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
    })
});
```

How can I achieve with Angular what jQuery does in this case?

Comment: you need to refactor all your code by thinking "angular". You're trying to put your jquery code in angular, that won't do.

Comment: yes, I agree. but can you give a little hint, how i could achieve this in an angluar way? it's kinda hard to get your head around doing this in angular, when you are used to work in jQuery and just start with angular. 
my use-case is: is want to get a json-file according to the data-id of the clicked element for loading further elements. here i could easily achieve this by also attaching the data-id to each child-element. but this doesn't seem very good code to me. would it be better to attach the data-id to each child-element by angular?  
or do I have to rethink from the absolute beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in this case the soultion was pretty easy, I could change my HTML to:

```
<div class="angulardiv" ng-click="myAlert(321);">ANGULAR
  <div class="sublement">
     Subelement
  </div>
</div>
```

...just passing the needed ID directly as a parameter to the function.

And then changed the Angular Code to:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myAlert = function(obj) {
        alert(obj);
    }
});
```